# Open datepicker only if condition is true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using a datepicker in my To Do List table that the user can use to select a certain date. I'm using it to select a certain "completed date" and I only want the datepicker to open if the To Do is marked 100% complete. Right now the datepicker will open if the To Do isn't marked 100%. Does anyone know how to add a conditional saying

```
if (todos[i].progress != 100) { *dont open datepicker* }
```

I've tried adding this to my event function but it does not work as I had hoped.

HTML: The last td element is for the datepicker.

```
tr class="rowTable dropdown-button" data-id="%todoID%" data-activates="todo_dropdown" data-context="true" data-type="edit-%canedit%" data-canedit="%canedit%" data-constrainwidth="false">
       <td class="tableData">
           <div class="checkbox" data-complete="%notTrue%" data-show="hidden">
               <div class="todo_checkbox"></div>
           </div>
       </td>
       <td class="tableData">%todoTitle%</td>
       <td class="tableData">%resources%</td>
       <td class="%isOverdue% tableData">%duedate%</td>
       <td class="tableData">%percentcomplete%</td>
       <td class="completedCalendar tableData"><input value="%dateCompleted%" class="datepicker picker_input" data-id="%todoID%" id="todo_completeddate" style="border:none" readonly="readonly"/></td>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.datepicker').on('change', function (e) {
       var $targ = $(e.currentTarget);
       var todoID = $targ.parents(".rowTable").data("id");
       var todos = currentItems;
       for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
           if (todoID == todos[i].id) {
               if (todos[i].progress == 100) {
                   var dateSet = $('.datepicker[data-id=' + todoID + ']').val();
                   todos[i].completed_date = dateSet;
               }
           }
       }
 })
```

Comment: do you possible to show working plnkr?

Comment: @Dipakchavda Idk cause the todos are coming from a server and I dont think Id be able to get them

Answer (score 0):

You can check your condition on change much like you're currently doing in your on change for the datePicker. This could be a change within the form, table, etc. Within that OnChange, you can check the condition and access the datepicker and hide it or show it like this

```
$(".datepicker").hide();
$(".datepicker").show();
```

Comment: If you mean the checkbox in the first <td> element, I have that set to when you click it, it sets the completed date to todays date. The datepicker is incase you want to change it to another date

Comment: @PatrickS I'm not sure of the conditions you need to check - but you can check when this form is updated and set the datepicker to show or hide like I mentioned above when the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using

```
beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        // check condition here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case you should disable/hide the date field when data are loaded from server.

You can also use `beforeShow` event of datepicker widget. But you'll not able to block opening datepicker window. You can hide calendar just after it is shown. Notice you have to use `setTimeout` in `beforeShow` otherwise it won't work.

```
  beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
      if (condition) {
        $(".foo").datepicker("widget").hide();
      }
    }, 0);
```

}

[See here for example](https://codepen.io/112g/pen/OQWyXZ)